# load data infile, comment character

Tags: mysql, load-data-infile

I have a data file where some rows are comment lines starting with %. How to load data from such a file into a mysql table?

Comment: There is not nearly enough information here.

Comment: @Tomalak, my question is, I do not know, how to write an  sql command to populate a table using data from a file, **while ignoring lines starting with '%'**. Is it now clear enough?

Comment: @Jim Linux, but why that is important?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ah. No. From the [spec](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/load-data.html) for the command there is no way to get it to ignore lines starting with a specific character. You can skip a certain number of lines, but that's the best you can do.

You'll want to preprocess the file. Or tell whoever is generating it to stop putting that in place.

Comment: I just wanted to confirm this. But I do not know why some one downvoted my qn.

Answer (score 2):

On Mac/Linux

```
grep -v '^%' datafile | mysql ....
```

On Windows

```
findstr /v ^% datafile | mysql ....
```

Comment: MY question says, the data file contains % and can mysql read by excluding those lines. I am not looking for pre-processing of data outside mysql.

Comment: Not with LOAD DATA INFILE.  It would be nice if there was a `LINES NOT STARTING BY`, which would do exactly what you want, but it doesn't seem to be available.  I think you're stuck with grep and a pipe.

Comment: I was not struck there..I also found that there was no LINES NOT STARTING BY in the spec. I was wondering if there is any other way other than pre processing data.

Comment: I seriously doubt it, other than writing your own stored procedure import, which is likely to be much slower.